# How to change/add chart data series in python-pptx?

Tags: python, charts, powerpoint

I'm trying to set data in an existing chart using python-pptx.

```
from pptx import Presentation
pres_path = "C:\\pres.pptx"
pres = Presentation(pres_path)

pres.slides[3].shapes[4].chart.series[0].values
```

(92.0, 330.0, 309.0, 313.0, 356.0, 421.0, 457.0)

```
pres.slides[3].shapes[4].chart.series[0].values = (1,2,3)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  AttributeError: can't set attribute
```

There's a method mentioned in the documentation which seems relevant, but I can't understand how to use it:
http://python-pptx.readthedocs.org/en/latest/_modules/pptx/chart/data.html

```
pres.slides[3].shapes[4].chart.replace_data((1,2,3))


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pptx\chart\chart.py", line 119, in     replace_data
    _SeriesRewriter.replace_series_data(self._chartSpace, chart_data)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pptx\chart\chart.py", line 197, in replace_series_data
sers = cls._adjust_ser_count(chartSpace, len(chart_data.series))
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'series'
```

I'd appreciate any help you can provide.
Thanks!

Comment: You may want to read [ask].

Comment: I edited the question, hope it's better this way.

Comment: Your best bet to get useful answers (or any at all), is to present what you already tried, as a minimal working demonstrative code.

Comment: That's actually what I did in my original post.
I tried to assign the new values where the current values are and got "AttributeError". 
Then I tried using the replace_data() and failed.

Comment: If you show the code you're using so far (that's not working), I'll answer for you. Only include the minimum needed to cause the error and include the full stack trace (error message) you receive.

Comment: I edited it again and added the code and the error messages.
Please tell me if you need anything else.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To add a new series to an existing table behind a chart you need to do 3 things:

1. create an instance of ChartData()
2. provide category name
3. add the new series to the ChartData() object, using the "add_series()" func.

   ```
   chart_data = ChartData()
   chart_data.categories = 'category_name'

   for col_idx, col in enumerate(single_df.columns):
       chart_data.add_series(col, (single_df.ix[:, col_idx].values))            

   shp.chart.replace_data(chart_data)
   ```