# Are series lines possible in python-pptx?

Tags: python, powerpoint, python-pptx

In powerpoint the lines connecting the two columns in the image below are called series lines. Is it possible to create these via python-pptx?

[image]

Comment: see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30821917/how-to-change-add-chart-data-series-in-python-pptx

Comment: There is currently no API support for series lines in `python-pptx`. If you want these you'll need to manipulate the underlying XML using a so-called "workaround function".